# Find own origin in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to find the origin of the current running script?
I would like to add a different behavior depending where the script was loaded from.

e.g. was loaded from:

```
http://localhost:8080/js/myscript.js
```

vs

```
http://www.myhost.com/js/myscript.js
```

I'm not the one who loads is so I can't add some info in load time, and the script is loaded dynamically using `$.getScript()`, so I can't look for the  element.

Comment: since your calling `$.getScript()` you already have that information. just assign the `url` to a parameter rather than entering the `url` directly then just check that parameter to find out where the script came from.

Comment: not cross-browser compatible at the moment, but interesting anyway: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.currentScript?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fdocument.currentScript

Comment: see my answer, should work.

Comment: @StefanNeubert that is exactly the API I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

When a script is called, unless it is marked as `defer` or `async`, it will always be the last element on the page at that moment in time (since it's blocking).

Using this, you can do the following:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script'),
    mylocation = scripts[scripts.length-1].getAttribute("src");
```

Then do with that whatever you want.

Comment: will that also work with JQuery getScript()?

Comment: I have no idea. Probably, but I really don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Well .., its kind of a hack..!

First you need to get all script elements

```
var all_scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
```

choose the current script

```
var current_script = all_scripts[all_scripts.length-1];
```

Now you can see the src of the script

```
alert(current_script.src);
```

Comment: I guess it's similar to @Kolink answer, but will it work with JQuery.getScript()?

Answer (score -3):

**UPDATED**
changed removed `var o = $(this)` as per @FelixKling suggestion

**UPDATED EXAMPLE**

```
$.getScript("http://localhost:8080/js/myscript.js")
    .done(function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {

        // this.url is the script url passed to $.getScript
        if(this.url.search('http://localhost:8080') != -1){
            alert("do one thing for http://localhost:8080/js/myscript.js");
        }
        if(this.url.search('http://www.myhost.com') != -1){
            alert("do another thing for http://www.myhost.com/js/myscript.js");
        }
    })
    .fail(function(){
        alert("somethign went wrong");
    });
```

<kbd>**[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8nHQ/4/)**</kbd>

Comment: You can avoid typing `o[0]` if you simply don't pass `this` to jQuery: `var o = this;` or just use `this.url` everywhere. `this` refers to the `jqXHR`, which is neither a DOM element nor an HTML string, so there is no reason to pass it to jQuery (`$`).

Comment: @milkshake I'm not sure how is that related to problem...

Comment: @GuyKorland because you can check directly which URL the `$getScript()` was using and do different behaviours based on that, just like your original question.

Comment: @milkshake But my code is in "http://jsfiddle.net/js/Actions.js" not in the loading function

Comment: @GuyKorland no but your question was how can I find out the origin of the script and this does exactly that, see my updated answer and see if it makes more sense.

Comment: @milkshake sorry but I guess I was miss understood, I'm not controlling the code that loads the script, I'm developing a library/script that is used by many others and loaded by them. And I want to know in the code (the library code) from where it was loaded.

Comment: @GuyKorland ah ok, well all you need to do is check `window.location.href` in your script.

Comment: @GuyKorland have you checked the new answer?

Comment: @milkshake as you probably know location.href and the scripts origin has nothing todo with each other. one can load scripts from anywhere on the web.

Comment: @GuyKorland so you are trying to find out if an external script (external to a 3rd party) is calling your script? im really confused with what you actually want to find out.

Comment: he wants to find the url of the loaded script, not the loading script.

Comment: my first answer did that but @GuyKorland said he didnt want that, he said he wanted to know who was running his script.

Comment: current answer (un-strikethough'ed) is has no relation to the question asked.